# How can I fix django error? "template does not exist"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I started Django few days ago and I am stuck now.
I got error like this.
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: home.html
but I don't know how to fix it.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import ToDoList, Item

def index(response, id):
ls = ToDoList.objects.get(id=id)
return render(response, "main/base.html", {"name":ls.name})

def home(response):
return render(response, "main/home.html", {'name':'test'})
```

**base.html**

```
<html> <head> <title>Website</title> </head> <body> <p>{{name}}</p> </body> </html>
```

**home.html**

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
```

Both html files are in file named templates
I thought template might have something to do with it and checked it.

**setting.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
'DIRS': [],
'APP_DIRS': True,
'OPTIONS': {
'context_processors': [
'django.template.context_processors.debug',
'django.template.context_processors.request',
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
],
},
},
]
```

Does someone help me out?

Comment: can u show the file structure of your project, then i can help out

Answer (score 1):

Just add your root template folder name to the DIRS value.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": ["templates"],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have both files in folder: `<project_name>/<app_name>/main/`, but you probably put it somewhere else.

Additionally, it's good practice to add this value to `TEMPLATES["DIRS"]`:

```
"DIRS": [os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "templates")],
```

and then create folder `"templates"` inside every app you have and store templates inside (move there your whole folder `"main"` with proper templates)

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
'DIRS': [
         os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates",
         os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"appname","templates")
        )],
'APP_DIRS': True,
'OPTIONS': {
'context_processors': [
'django.template.context_processors.debug',
'django.template.context_processors.request',
'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
],
},
},
]
```

Comment: Adding `"templates"` will be enough even if your templates folder inside your app

Comment: First templates means, templates folder inside your main project and second means, inside your app

Comment: Try and see yourself. The first is enough for Django to find the templates folder inside your apps too

Comment: sometimes in big project you have many apps so that time you will get error. I was getting the same error then i tried this

Comment: I don't agree. I am working on a big project and I checked this line before writing my answer. And Django doesn't care about the count of apps. If this is working for one app, this means it will also work for dozens. Do you know when you install a package to your project you don't add the package template to this section? Oh!  I can't imagine the `TEMPLATES` variable if it would be like you said.

Comment: Most Django packages have their own templates folder inside the package but none of them saying include the package path to the `TEMPLATES` variable in your `settings.py` file